# Sections - why do I need backticks here?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand sections and think I have got it.  Basically it is a way to apply partial application to binary operators.  So I understand all the `(2*)`, `(+1)`, etc. examples just fine.

But in the O'Reilly Real World Haskell book, Sections 'section' :) it has this example:

```
(`elem` ['a'..'z']) 'f'
>True
```

I understand the need for the parentheses - ie the section syntax.  But why do I need the backticks?

If I try, I get:

```
(elem ['a'..'z']) 'f'

<interactive>:220:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `[[Char]]' with actual type `Char'
    In the second argument of `elem', namely 'f'
    In the expression: (elem ['a' .. 'z']) 'f'
    In an equation for `it': it = (elem ['a' .. 'z']) 'f'
```

Comment: I think that you did a mistake coypasting: your second example should be without the backticks on `elem`, and without `>True` as answer.

Comment: @enrique Sorry I have corrected.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Haskell, the backtick turns a name to an infix operator:

```
a `elem` b = elem a b
```

So

```
(`elem` b) a = (\x -> x `elem` b) a
             = a `elem` b
             = elem a b
```

While

```
(elem b) a = elem b a
```

Comment: Using backticks to reverse a function's arguments in sections is pretty common, but it's arguably a hack, and clearer just to use `flip`.

Comment: @pash: I definitely agree (I'm surprised that opinion doesn't seem to be more common), but I think `elem` is a special case: it was written to be used infix, and I *expect* to see it used that way.  `div` and `mod` are similar examples.

Comment: @pash For what it's worth, hlint will recommend replacing instances of flip with using the function infix.

Comment: but ghci complains that it can't parse this input: foldl (`:`) [] [1..10] (it reverses the list [1..10])

Comment: @Oleg `:` is already an operator, you can't `\`:\` ` again. Use `flip` since other comments have suggested (`foldl (flip (:)) [] [1..10]`)